# Asp.Net web page does not load images on page load, but images load on button click

Tags: asp.net, .net, image, webforms

I am facing a scenario where I have displayed some images in Asp.Net List view control.
Everything works fine in visual studio debug mode, but the below problem occurs when I deploy the website.

**Scenario**- On the page load event, I call a method BindData() and this method fetches the data and binds the data in List view. I have a search button which also calls the BindData() and binds the same list view control.

**Problem**- When I deploy the website and open the page, the images are not loaded. But when I click search button, the images are visible.

Image tag inside List View
<asp:ImageButton ID="lnkHistory" runat="server" CommandName="History" CommandArgument='<%#Eval("RecordID") %>' Height="20px" Width="20px" ImageUrl="~/Images/History.png" />

[List View image on page load](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TdZqb.png)

[List View image showing images after clicking search button](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pmkUd.png)

Comment: I would clear my browser cache. And try using ctrl-f5 to force a re-load of the scripts for the browser page. I suspect that the original page might be broken - and stray images are showing.    it is assumed that those image links are in a folder that is part of the site? And you used VS to add + create the folder? (if you add the folder from windows explore, then VS might not see the web page, and thus when you publish, that folder of images is not being included. You might want to ftp into that web site, and check if your image folder was also published.

Comment: Cleared browser history + Cache. Ctrl+F5 done. Folder is already part of solution and is also present in deployment folder(including images). No luck till now.

Comment: gee, does older IE have a debug mode like new edge and chrome? You could try f12, and select elements - the picture element in the LV and see what gets spit out.

Answer (score 0):

Webforms can be tricky with these sometimes.

Sounds like something to do with either the browser or the local scripts.
Try the following:

1. Different Browser
2. Try a different image
3. Change the Height & Width. See if anything helps

Comment: Works on Edge, Chrome and all other browsers, except IE. Tried different image, no luck. Height & Width also didn't change anything.